# JW player black screen for IPAD

Tags: php, javascript, html, jwplayer

I am embedding my videos with JW player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/
and I have a problem with the videos not playing on Ipad or Iphone pretty much i think the HTML5 video tag.  The video is just black.  Code to embed the div

```
 <div id="jwplayer-1"></div>     
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('jwplayer-1').setup(
{"flashplayer":"<?php echo $jwplayer_folder; ?>/player.swf",
"width":"550",
"height":"500",
"controlbar":"bottom",
"icons":"true","playlist.position":"none","playlistsize":"180","repeat":"none",
"shuffle":"false","bufferlength":"1",
"smoothing":"true",
"stretching":"uniform",
"wmode":"opaque",
"mute":"false",
"volume":"90",
"skin":"<?php echo $jwplayer_folder; ?>/skins/whotube.zip",
"dock":"false",
"autostart":"false",
"file":"http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
"image":"<?php echo $image_slug; ?>",
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine on the flash end it plays the video on any normal browser but on the ipad the video well not play.  I know it is not encoding issue or anything because i use this code right under the video and it works...

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="<?php echo $video_slug ?>" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Any thoughts or ideas as I have tried everything I think it is probably the way i am seting up the JW player on the setup method?

Thanks!

Comment: Yu are loading the setup() method with incorrect properties, Please see my answer for the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understand your problem now,

The below code seems to work on iPad/iPhone , [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/HTM4s/7/)

This method supports Flash Fallback as well, But mainly plays HTML5 Video(Provided that Video has no encoding issues.)

You can now Use Php to dynamically load image,video,jw folder names etc.
If you want to completely get rid of flash support, remove
 `{ type: 'flash',  src:'http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf'}` from the modes node!

```
<script src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<p><div id="exampleHTML"></div></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer('exampleHTML').setup({
    height: 360,
    image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/bkaovAYt-720.jpg",
    levels: [
        { file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-injeKYZS.mp4", type:"video/mp4" },
        { file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-27m5HpIu.webm", type:"video/webm" }
    ],
    modes: [
        { type: 'html5' },
        { type: 'flash',  src:'http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf'}
    ],
    width: 640
});
</script>​
```

Screenshot of Video Playing on iPad:
[image]
Also keep in mind that there are limitations with jw HTML5 Player, You can find them [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/14625/html5-support)

Comment: hey thanks for taking the time to respond. My problem is that the Jwplayer implementation of the HTML5 video tag is not working properly...  the extra video tag i provided for my example was to show that it is working when i use the video tag myself so the encoding of my videos should work.  Again the JW player is not handling the HTML5 video tag properly or something.. That is my problem.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Hi , Got it, I updated the Answer with the updated jw embed code, Try to generate The above code using Php.

Comment: wow thanks so much When i get a chance ill try it and report back!

Comment: you can check the working demo, and If this is useful, Please Accept the Answer and Vote Up my Anser. Cheers-

Comment: thanks for your help.  It ended up being a combination of two things.  What you mentioned above helped me to find the answer.  Which was that i was including the jwplayer.js twice. so matter what i did the video tag wouldn't work properly but flash did.  thanks AGAIN!